# Error con la funcion "function bind_param() on boolean"

Tags: php

Tengo un error con una línea de php, y no encuentro el error.

```
function existingEmail($Email){
    global $mysqli;
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE Email = ? LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $Email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $num = $stmt->num_rows;
    $stmt->close();
    if ($num > 0){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

> `#1 {main} thrown in functions.php on line 116`

```
$stmt->bind_param('ssssisi', $Email, $User, $Password_hash, $active, $token, $user_type);

if ($stmt->execute()){
    return $mysqli->insert_id;
} else {
    return 0;
}
```

Hola critical la linea 116 es esta: que estaria en functions.php

```
(Linea 115-) $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (Email, User, Password, active, token, id_type) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"); 
(Linea 116 -) $stmt->bind_param('ssssisi', $Email, $User, $Password_hash, $active, $token, $user_type);
```

Pero también tengo error en la linea 62 que esta en el register.php junto al codigo html:

```
$register = registerUser($Email, $User, $Password_hash, $active, $token, $user_type);
```

Y el error total es:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\dev\login\php\functions.php:116 
Stack trace: 
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\dev\login\register.php(62): registerUser('admin@sqlz.com', 'admin1', '$2y$10$fOUDVQnB...', 0, 'afff25d132889d5...', 2) 
#1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\dev\login\php\functions.php on line 116
```

Si es un formulario de register y login

Para ejecutar este php, es necesario el archivo connection.php con conexión a la base de datos, el cual esta incluido apenas comienza el codigo

Comment: Hola amigo puedes decirme cual es la linea 116 XD

Comment: supongo que estas haciendo un register o algo parecido?

Comment: $stmt->bind_param('sssisi', $Email, $User, $Password_hash, $active, $token, $user_type); en el bim_paran pasas 7 elemento y luego de das 6 variables, chekea esto y me dices

Comment: ¿A qué consulta pertenece este código: `$stmt->bind_param('ssssisi', $Email, $User, $Password_hash, $active, $token, $user_type);`? ...  Por otra parte, el uso de globales en por lo general considerado una mala práctica. Mejor incluye un archivo de conexión o maneja la conexión mediante instancias de clase.

Comment: Tu `prepare` intenta declarar 7 placeholders para 6 campos, luego te retorna `false` en vez de un objeto mysqli_statement. Obviamente el booleano `false` no tiene métodos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo diría que no hay ningún error en `registerUser` ni en el archivo `register.php` de por sí.

El error está en que al hacer:

```
$register = registerUser($Email, $User, $Password_hash, $active, $token, $user_type);
```

pasas 6 parámetros:

1. Email
2. User
3. Password_hash
4. active
5. token
6. user_type

Pero luego intentas preparar la sentencia con siete placeholders:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (Email, User, Password, active, token, id_type) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
```

Cuando debiera ser:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (Email, User, Password, active, token, id_type) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
```

Como le pasaste siete, la salida de `$mysqli->prepare` retorna `false` en vez de un objeto `mysqli_statement`. Luego cuando intentas invocar un método sobre `false` claramente no se puede.

Sin embargo, aunque corrigieras el error en la línea 115, de nuevo intentas bindear más parámetros que los que tienes:

```
$stmt->bind_param('ssssisi', $Email, $User, $Password_hash, $active, $token, $user_type);
```

Cuando debiera ser:

```
$stmt->bind_param('sssisi', $Email, $User, $Password_hash, $active, $token, $user_type);
```

Finalmente, lo que te dice A.Cedano es muy cierto, evita las variables globales. Ese código es propenso a fallas y es imposible de testear. Sería mejor si pasas el objeto de conexión como parámetro:

```
function existingEmail($Email, $mysqli){
    $stmt = $mysqli->....
}
```

**Bonus Track:**

En esta pregunta, y en muchas otras que se ven en [Stack Overflow Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com), llama la atención que un error en el driver `mysql` (obsoleto) o `mysqli` devuelva **FALSE** en vez de gatillar un error o una excepción.

Esto obliga a que el manejo de errores sea del tipo

```
$salida = $conexión->método( $parámetros);

if($salida === false) {
  ... manejo del error...
  return $conexión->error;
} 
...manejo del resultado...
return $resultado;
```

Como verán, para saber qué salió mal, tienes que consultar **adicionalmente** el contenido de [conexión->error](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.error.php).

Usando el driver PDO, cuya sintaxis es muy, muy similar a `mysqli` tú puedes decirle que transforme esos errores internos en excepciones:

Por ejemplo al instanciar la conexión:

```
$conexión = new PDO($dsn, $usuario, $contraseña);
$conexión->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

De ahí en adelante, se puede operar al estilo:

```
try {

  $salida = $conexión->método( $parámetros );
  ... procesamiento con el resultado...
  return $resultado;

} catch (\PDOException $e) {

  ... manejo del error ...
  return $e->getMessage(); (o bien la traza de la excepcion como string)

}
```

La excepción ya tiene un mensaje propio, y uno se ahorra un paso.

Esta ventaja es más notoria cuando quieres preparar una consulta y luego ejecutarla. En `mysqli` tendrías que hacer:

```
$statement = $conexión->prepare( $parámetros);

if($statement === false) { // comprobación 1
  ... manejo del error...
  return $conexión->error; // además preguntar cuál fue el error
} 

$salida = $statement->método( $otros_parámetros ) // bind, execute, etc

if($salida === false) {
  ... manejo del error...
  return $conexión->error;  // comprobación 2
}
...manejo del resultado...  // ...y preguntar por el error
return $resultado;
```

Mientras que en PDO el mismo bloque try/catch puede envolver todo:

```
try {

  $statement = $conexión->prepare( $parámetros );

  $salida = $conexión->método($otros_parámetros);

  ... procesamiento con el resultado...
  return $resultado;

} catch (\PDOException $e) {  // entras sin tener que comprobar la salida o el statement

  ... manejo del error ...
  return $e->getMessage(); // ya contiene todo lo que necesitas saber

}
```

Me pareció oportuno el comentario para mostrar que, a mi juicio, el flujo de un programa es mucho más entendible (y tiene menos [Ciclomatic Complexity](https://phpmd.org/rules/codesize.html)) cuando uno se acostumbra a manejar excepciones en vez de comprobar cosas tan inconsistentes como que un error en la DDBB retorne `FALSE`. Y con todo lo que me gusta y defiendo PHP, una de las cosas desesperantes que tiene son las inconsistencias.

Comment: Muchas gracias!, eres un genio, ya he podido resolver el problema!

Comment: @sqk si la respuesta te soluciono el problema te sugiero aceptar la respuesta, en la palomita a la izquierda de la respuesta.